# Установить обложку для записи в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Каким образом в WordPress можно установить, скажем так, обложку для каждой записи? Чтобы на выводи записи было сначала изображение, а потом текст записи.
Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода миниатюр в теме оформления WordPress используется специальная функция `the_post_thumbnail()`.

```
<?php if (function_exists ('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail () ) {
    the_post_thumbnail (); 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

В редактировании записи, в правом нижнем углу "задать миниатюру". Позволяет добавить изображение к любой записи и выводить в нужных местах.

Answer (score 2):

Для загрузки изображений используйте миниатюры записи. Если при создании записи вы не находите поля для загрузки миниатюры, включите её поддержку, добавив следующий код в файл темы `functions.php`:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post','page'));
}
```

Далее в цикле вывода постов используйте функцию `the_post_thumbnail()` для вывода миниатюры